# Tomcat is creating new sessions with Chrome and not with Firefox

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I'm testing my web on Tomcat, and I can see a curious behaviour when I'm monitoring the sessions list from Tomcat manager:

- If I refresh the page (pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>) using **Firefox**, everything goes ok: no new session is created
- If I refresh the page (pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>) using **Chrome**, a new session is created. And this happens everytime I refresh the page (3 hits to <kbd>F5</kbd> = 3 new sessions).

Edit: the same happens using <kbd>F5</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>

What's happening? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: check if chrome is sending the jsessionid cookie

Comment: I do remember there were some gotchas, when domain was `localhost`, `Chrome` had some issues when you try set cookie on just `localhost` because it was treated as `TLD` (just like it's impossible to set cookie on `.com`). I don't know whether they fixed it but anyway try to run your application on some other adres like `my-app.local` and map `127.0.0.1` to it via `/etc/hosts`